# Ai Thinker A7 module does not lock GPS

Tags: gps

I am using A7 module from Ai Thinker for GPRS and GPS. However, what I notice is that,

1. The A7 module does not lock GPS
2. When the GPS application on Android Phone shows 13 detected GPS satellites, the A7 module struggles to detect even 3. The best I have seen so far is 4 satellite. But it did not lock the GPS.

I took the module in open area and kept it ON for 15 to 20 mins without any luck.

I used commands like AT+GPS=1 and AT+AGPS=1 to enable GPS.
Am I missing something here.
Any help in this regards would be useful.

Comment: I'm going to ask a stupid question here:  You do have a GPS antenna connected, right?  If the antenna is connected, are you sure it is the correct type (powered, most likely) and the cable is in good shape (not broken or bent sharply?). I ask because you don't mention the antenna, and I don't see mention of that module being sold with a GPS antenna - only that it has a connector for one.

Comment: Were you able to get it working for GPS?

Answer (score 1):

Hello I would take a look at this video.
https://youtu.be/H7eBurjWC0k,
It shows that the supplied anntena for his module was actually a 2.4 wifi anntena not suitable for gps, once a cheap ebay gps antenna was connected the module works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I am testing A7. GPS works fine. Guess you are listening to the GPS port and attached the external antenna.

Use AT+GPSRD = 1 ( to have a 1 sec frequency reporting in your normal port. )

Comment: Hi @SKC , i am using a external GPS antenna but i am not able to get it working , do you have any sample code and the connections between the arduino and A7 module which you can include in your answer